# How to use the same connection datasource on Tomcat and Glassfish?

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, glassfish, jndi

I like to test my web application with Hibernate on a local Tomcat installation and deploy it later to a Glassfish server.

Connection datasource for Tomcat looks like this:

```
<property name="connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb</property>
```

Glassfish path:

```
<property name="connection.datasource">jdbc/mydb</property>
```

Would it be possible to consolidate these two settings, in order that I could use only one hibernate.cfg.xml for my runtime environemnt?

Answer (score 0):

The better approach is to use two (or more) hibernate.cfg.xml configuration files, one for each environment and/or database.

Most part of the configuration file can be the same for both files (especially the references for the mapping files). Only some parts like the connection string, the user/password or the database driver differ (if necessary).

Then you give the path and the filename of the configuration file as a start parameter for your application and use it in `Configuration.configure(<filename>)`.

The advantages are:
- no problems with different connection strings
- no problems with different passwords for test and production
- possibility to use different databases (p. ex. Oracle and MySQL).
- if a table changes in only one environment, you can easily reference to a different mapping file
=> and all this with the same Java code for both environments.

Comment: Thx for your proposal. This approach has one significant disadvantage. Every change on the hibernate configuration must be done twice. It's prone to error and not convenient for a development environment.

Answer (score 0):

With copy and paste it is not a real problem using two hibernate configuration files.

If you absolutely want to have only one file, you create the hibernate.cfg.xml with all what is the same in both environments and you include a second file which only contains the connection string.

For example like this in hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
      "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" [
   <!ENTITY database_connection SYSTEM "databaseConnection.xml">
  ]>

<hibernate-configuration>

  <session-factory>

&database_connection;

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <mapping resource="..."/>
    ...
    <mapping resource="..."/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Then you need a second file `databaseConnection.xml` which contains the connect info, and which is included automatically when reading the configuration. This file you have in two versions, one for Tomcat, one for Glassfish. If you change your mappings, you only need to do it in one file, but you have to pay attention with the second file when you deliver your software.

Me personally I think the version with two hibernate.cfg.xml files is easier and more flexible.

(By the way, including files is an xml feature, *not* a hibernate feature.)

Comment: Yes, including a XML file with the common settings could be an approach for me! Thanks for your advice. I didn't know this xml feature.